# How to get value from same span class in a div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get phone number from span which is 011 92100355 and 011 37653145 and address from h4 tag which is  AB 14,Harua chor Market, New POndichery India

```
<div class="grid_16 bbd pb5 pt5">
    <div class="grid_16 column alpha phone-details ">
        <div id="resinfo-phone" class="p-relative">
            <div class="bold ttupper res-main-label column alpha">Phone:</div>
            <div class="grid_14 column omega res-main-phone">
                <div class="phone left" id="phoneNoString">
                    <div class="column alpha omega">
                        <span class="telephone">
                            <span class="tel">011 92100355</span>,
                            <span class="telephone">011 37653145</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_16">
        <div class="res-main-address clearfix">
            <div class="bold res-main-label column alpha ttupper">Address:</div>
            <div class="grid_14 column omega">
                  <h4 class="res-main-address-text left">
 AB 14, <strong itemprop="addressLocality">Harua</strong> Chor Market, New Pondichery
 <span class="hidden" itemprop="addressCountry">India</span></h4>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried this code for getting address and phone number but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.grid_16.bbd.pb5.pt5').find('span').each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Please define "not working". What results are you getting, what results do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var tel = [];

        $(".telephone span").each(function(i,v) {

            tel[i] = $.trim($(this).text());
        });

        var address =$("h4.res-main-address-text").text();

        console.log(tel);
        console.log(address);
    });
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6YSXC/13/)

Comment: How about to wrap all code with `$(document).ready` for safety?

Comment: @Regent Without document ready it should not work .. All jquery code should wrap in $(document).ready

Comment: @Bala that's what I'm talking about, yes. And yes, "safety" wasn't right word there

Comment: @Regent see this link http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/  .what is use of document ready ..the code will be executed after document is loaded (dom loaded )..

Comment: @Bala well, I know what it is. I suggested to edit answer by adding `$(document).ready` to make answer completed.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(".grid_16").find("h4").text(); //address
  $(".grid_16").find("span").text();// phone no
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6YSXC/15/)